# Model in saved world file unexpectedly merges into one object

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi guys, I am new to Gazebo and am following one of the tutorials. I have created a model using Model Editor in Gazebo. After saving the model file and importing the model in a new Gazebo instance, my model's links and joints are all combined into a single object (I can't move or rotate the individual objects eg: wheel). They are also transparent for some reason. Is this normal or is it a bug? How do I disable the unification of model parts in future world file saves? Is it also possible to regain control over individual objects of my current model?

Kindly advise.

My Model:
https://i.imgur.com/wm96bR6.png

Version details:
https://i.imgur.com/PV0EGfb.png

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/29224/model-in-saved-world-file-unexpectedly-merges-into-one-object/) by [scottie](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/194039/scottie/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So my mistake was jumping into Model Editor mode directly after importing the model. This doesn't specify that the recently imported model is model that is being edited. To edit an existing model, we need to right click on the model > Choose Edit Model.

- Out of the Model Editor mode, the parts of a model would seem to be a single unit (which makes sense since the model parts make up a single model eg: wheel parts on a car model make up the car model)
- We can regain control over individual objects of our current model by jumping into edit mode of that particular model.

Reference Image:
https://i.imgur.com/v3gYZIh.png

This is already documented in Gazebo: https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=model_editor#Editexistingmodels

---

Originally posted by [scottie](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/194039/scottie/) with karma: 1 on 2023-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0